# Content Type of POST request payload

Tags: json, xml, rest, go, http-post

I am sending a JSON body in my POST Request, but http.DetectContentType is identifying it as a text/plain type.

I want to have flexibility to process request payload based on their content type - if XML {}  if JSON {} else {NO Processing}

To achieve this conditional processing, I am using http.DetectContentType to return the content type o the request but it is returning text/plain is every scenario.

```
func Test(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) *ErrorObject {

        reqBuffer := make([]byte, 512)
        _, err := r.Body.Read(reqBuffer)
        if err != nil {

    return ErrorObject{}.New(1, err, nil)
}

contentType := GetContentType(reqBuffer)
fmt.Printf(contentType)

    if contentType == "application/xml" || contentType == "text/xml" {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=UTF-8") ...}
    if contentType == "application/json" || contentType == "text/json" {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8") ... } 
    else return Invalid Request Type error
} 

   func GetContentType(buffer []byte) string {

       fmt.Println(string(buffer))
       contentType := http.DetectContentType(buffer)
       fmt.Printf(contentType)
       return contentType

    }
```

Expect to return the function - Content Type as application/json but getting text/plain

Using POSTMAN to send request to server with Body as raw and JSON

```
    {
      "data": [
         {
           "group": "TEST",
           "name": "TEST",
           "released": true,
           "version": 1,
           "teststeps": [
              {
                   "bin": 32,
                   "comment": "PAA",
                   "dataType": "J",
                   "format": "R6.2",
                   "id": "PAA3",
                   "osg": 8,
                   "usg": 0
              }
            ],
           "parameters": [
              {
                  "comment": "test",
                  "description": "test",
                  "format": "R7.0",
                  "id": 1,
                  "teststepId": "PAA",
                  "value": 30,
                  "type": "teststep"
            }
          ]
        }
     ]
  }
```

Comment: Have you added "Content-Type : application/json" into your Postman request header?

Comment: It's generally the client's responsibility to set the Content-Type header correctly when sending the request. You shouldn't need to detect it at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am using http.DetectContentType to return the content type o the request but it is returning text/plain is every scenario.

According to the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#DetectContentType) `DetectContentType` *"... implements the algorithm described at https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/ to determine the Content-Type of the given data"*. The algorithm there is primarily for handling content types which the browser can handle by itself.

And if you look  [at the actual code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/sniff.go) you'll see that it does not care about `application/json` or similar at all and that it returns `text/plain` for anything which looks non-binary (and was not matched before as with `text/html`).

In other words: this is the wrong tool for the job. The proper way would be for the client to specify what kind of content is sent using the `Content-Type` header and not to let the server guess the kind of content.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but I am creating an API which can handle both types, as there are two different web application which would use this API and one has XML payload and other has JSON. That's why I want to handle it on the client side request handler, in case of XML payload I would like to convert it to JSON and call my core APIs which accept JSON format. IS there any other package or library which you can suggest ?

Comment: @soamya as already mentioned in the answer and in the comments you do not need a library, all you need is to check the Content-Type header of the request to find out the type of the content of the body. If that header is not provided by the client that sends the request then you need to fix that side, not the back-end.

Comment: Got It ! Thanks !